# Python, add variable's names to a list/dict

Tags: python, list

i'm a beginner in POO.

I'm actually coding a game with pygame and i want to add variable's names to a list or a dict.

I have a class Hero with that **init**

```
class Hero:
    def __init__(self, posx, posy, image) :
        self.name = "Hero"

        self.posx = posx
        self.posy = posy

        self.image = pygame.image.load(image).convert_alpha()

        self.width = self.image.get_rect()[2]
        self.height = self.image.get_rect()[3]
```

and i have a function to show sprite on the screen:

```
def show(self) :
    display.blit(self.image, (self.posx, self.posy))
```

It works, there's no problems, I'm actually using this:

```
captainamerica = Hero(100,400, "sprites/captainamerica/base.png")
captainamerica.show()
ironman = Hero(100,400, "sprites/ironman/base.png")
ironman.show()
```

But i want to use this:

```
listhero = []
listhero.append(captainamerica)
listhero.append(ironman)
i = 0
while i < len(listhero):
    listhero[i].show()
```

It doesn't work cause it take the variable's values and not the variable's names.

Thank you for your helps and sorry if my english was bad.

Comment: what do you mean by *it doesn't work* ? you should increment  `i` inside the *while loop* or even better use a *forloop* like this: `for hero in listhero: hero.show()`

Comment: just add the following line just above the show definition in the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actualy use dictionary:

```
dictheroes = {}

dictheroes['ironman'] = Hero(100,400, "sprites/ironman/base.png")
```

Comment: I'm bad with dicts but i try this, i'll come in few minutes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are not incrementing i, so this results in an infinite loop.

You could add

```
i += 1
```

at the end of your loop.

Even better, do this:

```
for h in listhero:
    h.show()
```

With regards to your choice of datastructure, as was highlighted in the comments, using a dictionary is better than using a list. You can do something like this:

```
heroes = {}
heroes['Captain America'] = Hero(100, 400, 'sprites/captainamerica/base.png')
```

Comment: I just don't copy that line from my code, but thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the list, you can also do

```
[h.show() for h in listhero]
```

You can use the dictionary, but the order of the blit will not be the order of insert in the dict. If you need to preserve the order of blit, continue with the list or use a :

```
collections.OrderedDict
```